# PHP namespaces problems

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to use an external library.
Because there are some conflicts I'm using namespaces ( php 5.3 )

The goal is not to change the external library at all ( just adding the namespaces at the top)

The problem is inside the library there are several situations that don't work

- `is_a($obj,'3thpartyclassname')` only  works if I add the namespace in front of 3thpartyclassname
- the 3th party uses native classes but they don't work only if I apped the global space (`new \Exception`)

Any way to make this work with no modifications ?

Update
use \Exception as Exception; fix problem 2

I only have problems with is_a and is_subclass_of. Both of them need the namespace and ignore the current namespace.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you have to do some modifications

```
namespace My\Own\Namespace;                // declare your own namespace
use My\ThirdParty\Component;               // import 3rd party namespace
$component = new Component;                // create instance of it
var_dump(is_a($component, 'Component'));   // FALSE
var_dump($component instanceof Component); // TRUE
```

The `is_a` and `is_subclass_of` methods require you to put in the fully qualified classname (including the namespace). To my knowledge, there is no way around that as of PHP 5.3.5. Using `instanceof` should solve both bases though.

Importing the native classes, like Exception should also work, e.g.

```
namespace My\Own\Namespace;
use \Exception as Exception;
throw new Exception('something broke');
```

See the [chapter on Namespace in the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to make is_a() respect relative namespaces (such as the current namespace or a namespace imported with a `use` command).  This is because it takes a string argument and executes in a different context.  You'd need to switch to the `instanceof` syntax instead.  So no, I don't think that this will help you avoid collisions between libraries which both are written against the global namespace, you'll still have to find instances like this and address them directly.